# Alguien que tenga la amabilidad de decirme que esta mal hace tiempo que tengo este problema Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: excepciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me puede ayudar con esto

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados) || Por favor, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. Y por cierto, el código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: Buenas! He revisado tu pregunta y tengo algunas recomendaciones que hacer. 1 - Lee [Un Fragmento de Código vale más que mil Imagenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880) para que entiendas por que tu pregunta podría no ser bien recibida y terminar cerrada y/o con votos negativos.